# How to get specific element Count in XML variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider this XML:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Aba</Name>
        <LName>Aba</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

I declare a `XML` variable and assign this XML to that. How I can get count of `ID` elements in this XML variable using Sql Server 2008 (TSQL)?

Comment: Can you load it into a .NET XDocument?   From there you can load the root as an XElement and get the count via XElement.Elements.Count().

Comment: You might be able to do it in TSQL using XQuery and nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @xmlvar XML;
set @xmlvar ='<YOUR XML>';
select @xmlvar.value('count(/Employees/Person/ID)', 'INT') AS 'Count'
```

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT @XMLVariable.value('count(/Employees/Person/ID)', 'int') AS IDCount
```